# Want to declare pointer to map

Tags: c++

How can I declare a pointer to map, how can I insert element into this map and how can I iterate through the elements of this map?

Answer (score 6):

Declaring a pointer to map is a really suspicious desire. Anyway, it would be done like this

```
#include <map>

typedef std::map<KeyType, ValueType> myMap;
myMap* p = new myMap();
p->insert(std::make_pair(key1, value1));
...
p->insert(std::make_pair(keyn, valuen));

//to iterate
for(myMap::iterator it = p->begin(); it!=p->end(); ++it)
{
   ...
}
```

Again, a pointer to a map is a horrible option. In any case, google for std::map

Comment: A pointer to a map is perfectly normal. Nothing suspicious about it at all.

Comment: I tend to avoid pointers because RAII is way more comfortable. Sometimes you don't have any choice because your data must be referenced in two different containers. However a map is a container, so it would be a pervert situation where a map must be referenced by two other containers.

Comment: @Fecal Brunch: Because it's almost always a sign that people are trying to allocate a map on the heap. And that in turn is often the result of the (mistaken) assumption that a map must always contain one element, and if you've got no elements you should have a `NULL` map pointer instead. (Wrong of course, maps can be empty.)

Comment: It is not always horrible. copying maps is expensive. Of course you might put it into a shared_ptr. Or have a map instance inside a class and put the instance of that into shared_ptr. Most of the time you don't want to copy them.

Comment: The fact remains that if you're creating `std::map` pointers because copying them is expensive, then you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Cashcow Why would you pass a pointer to a map to avoid copying?! Just pass a reference to the map you have, and keep it in place.

Comment: A pointer is a 'stateful' reference: it can be zero. This is often useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    typedef std::map<int, int> IntMap;

    IntMap map;
    IntMap* pmap = &map;

    (*pmap)[123] = 456;
    // or
    pmap->insert(std::make_pair(777, 888));

    for (IntMap::iterator i=pmap->begin(); i!=pmap->end(); ++i) {
        std::cout << i->first << "=" << i->second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```